# Insert Value Of Selected Radio Button in Array

Tags: jquery

I am Trying to Insert the Selected Value of the checbox into an Array and display the array value.. However I got this error `valueSelected.push is not a function`.. Can Anyone help me? Here's my code. Are there anything that I missed Out?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="dataTbl">
            <tr>
                <td><input type='checkbox' id='chkVerify' name='chkVerify' value='Item1'></td>
                <td>Item 1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type='checkbox' id='chkVerify' name='chkVerify' value='Item2'></td>
                <td>Item 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type='checkbox' id='chkVerify' name='chkVerify' value='Item3'></td>
                <td>Item 3</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <button type="button" class="deletebutton" name="delete_video" title="Show Selected Value" onclick="DelRow();">Show Selected Value</button>

        <script>
            function DelRow(){
                var checkboxValArry=[];
                var $chkbox_checked    = $('tbody input[type="checkbox"]:checked', '#dataTbl');
                 if($chkbox_checked.length === 0){
                    alert("No Row Selected");
                 }

                 else{
                    var checkedBox = $('#chkVerify:checked');
                        for (var i=0; i<checkedBox.length; i++){
                            var valueSelected = $('#chkVerify:checked').val();
                            checkboxValArry = valueSelected.push();
                            alert(checkboxValArry);
                        }

                 }

            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`valueSelected` is a string .

`Push` is only for array.

Moreover your are not pushing element correctly.

Try like this

```
checkboxValArry.push(valueSelected);
console.log(checkboxValArry);
```

EDIT

Your data retrive part is wrong

Try like this

```
var checkboxValArry=[];
$('#chkVerify:checked').each(function(){
   checkboxValArry.push($(this).val());
})
console.log(checkboxValArry);
```

Comment: Thanks.. It works.. But the value returns is incorrect.. If I click on Item 1 and Item 2, the value in  the array should be Item1, Item2.. But It returns Item1, Item1

Comment: @NurWafiqa i have updated my answer .. just use `.each` instead of for loop

Comment: Okay. Thanks.. I will give a try

Comment: Yes.. It Works.. Thanks A lot

Comment: @NurWafiqa id must be unique .. you should use class for mutiple name instead of mutiple same id

Comment: @NurWafiqa hmm ..  all the best (y)

Answer (score 1):

You may simply use jQuery `map` method to do all the heavy lifting for you.

```
if($chkbox_checked.length === 0){
     alert("No Row Selected");
}
else
{       
      checkboxValArry = $chkbox_checked.map(function(){
                               return this.value;
                        }).get();;
      console.log(checkboxValArry);                  
}
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/tiweyi/edit?html,js,console,output) is a working sample

Also, i noticed that you have same id value for more than one checckbox. That is invalid. You should keep unique id values.